# Teradata to Hadoop using Sqoop: query without sample does not work

Tags: hadoop, teradata, sqoop

I'm trying to copy a table from a Teradata table to HDFS using Sqoop. The connector works and if the query contains a `sample` directive everything is ok:

```
sqoop import --connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataConnManager --verbose --num-mappers 1 --target-dir '/user/test/finalfolder' -query "select * from p_dd.mytable sample 10; "
```

but if I want to copy the entire table using `select *` the jobs finishes without errors but no files are created:

```
sqoop import --connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataConnManager --verbose --num-mappers 1 --target-dir '/user/test/finalfolder' -query "select * from p_dd.mytable ;"
```

How can I use a query to copy an entire table from Teradata to HDFS?

Comment: Can you check the command for --query , in your code its a single - before query instead of 2 -

Comment: Tests with `--query` didn't change anything.

Comment: How can you query without  connect, username and password params

Comment: I'm simplified the conections parameters to show only what I need. I have user and password on my entire sqoop command

Comment: Have you run the SELECT statement against the database using SQL Assistant or Teradata Studio Express to see what happens?

Comment: Yes. The exact same SQL command gives me all rows from that table. The problem is only with Sqoop and the SQL query without any conditions.  I even tried a query with sample 10000000 and it worked, so it's something on the interaction between Sqoop and Teradata with a query without any conditions.

Comment: I can even export the data using Fast Connect from Studio Express (Linux). The query that the exporter creates is exactly the same as mine on Sqoop.